# Ruby on Rails capture webcam video and audio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, video, rubygems, capture

Is there any gem out there that can interact with users webcam to capture video and audio and upload it to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard about navigator.getUserMedia()? That could the trick. More info: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

They talk about it in the Mobile Web Development course in Udacity (lesson 10).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6mzYt5fJpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried headshot ? 
I just tried it yesterday, but ran into some trouble with the flash player, not beeing able to set permissions for camera use
try it out, its easy to add to your application, maybe you'll make it work.
and better backup your files before.