# Can you use a webcam with ruby-opencv in realtime?

Tags: c++, ruby, opencv

I'm thinking of building a quick and dirty script to help a friend out. It will need to take webcam input and perform very simple computation on it (think delta brightness of the pixels over time, relatively computationally simple).

I am currently leaning towards c++ [like so](http://opencvlover.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/accesing-camera-using-opencv.html) along with [opencv](http://opencv.org/) but I was wondering, since it's such a computationally inexpensive task, (relatively speaking of course) if there was a way to simply use [ruby-opencv](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv) or some other techniques to keep it in a scripting language.

I haven't been able to find any way to import realtime webcamera images into a ruby script since I've been looking but I'd be more than happy to have my search skills proven inadequate by the wonderful SO community!

Places I've looked so far:

[hornetseye](http://www.wedesoft.de/hornetseye-api/)

[c++ script (what I'm leaning towards)](http://rubydu.de/articles/02-a-simple-opencv-program-to-access-your-webcam/)

[using an ffi](http://www.sitepoint.com/detecting-faces-with-ruby-ffi-in-a-nutshell/)

In summary; Is there a way to import realtime webcamera images into a ruby script to perform simple computation on them? (I was thinking with opencv but am not tied to any particular idea.

Comment: If you're not committed to Ruby, OpenCV does have Python bindings.

Comment: @Aurelius I'm not commited to ruby, python sounds great, can I access a webcam in realtime with it? can you show me any docs/blog_posts/whatever on how to do that? if so, post as an answer, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: I've been struggelin, too
but this one works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205049/ruby-on-rails-capture-webcam-video-and-audio/22236878#22236878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV has Python bindings which will call native C++ code under the hood. They also have many tutorials on how to use the Python API. A basic example of opening a video feed can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video), and a longer list of tutorials is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html). I highly recommend looking through them if you are interested in doing much work with OpenCV.

A brief summary of the first tutorial:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Do image processing here, using frame

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [ruby-opencv](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv) you can capture and display camera images as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'opencv'
include OpenCV
FPS = 30
input = CvCapture.open
win = GUI::Window.new 'video'
loop do
  img = input.query
  win.show img
  key = GUI.wait_key 1000 / FPS
  break if key and key.chr == "\e"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [hornetseye-v4l2](http://wedesoft.github.io/hornetseye-v4l2/) and [hornetseye-xorg](http://wedesoft.github.io/hornetseye-xorg/) you can capture and display camera images like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'hornetseye_v4l2'
require 'hornetseye_xorg'
include Hornetseye
input = V4L2Input.new
X11Display.show { input.read }
```